# Don't understand how JavaScript works with operator

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I just fall into a situation like that. I tried to add "10"+1 which gives me " 101" Which is obvious as I know that it concate string with numeric and convert it to string of 101 but when write "10"-1 then it gives me 9. I how is this working

Comment: "Type coercion"

Answer (score 1):

Because the `-` operator cannot be applied to strings (for obvious reasons - how do you subtract a string?), it's implicitly converted to a number. So this:

```
"10" - 1
```

Is converted behind the scenes to:

```
10 - 1
```

Which is obviously:

```
9
```

For more information, look up *type coercion*.

Comment: so the answer will be in string or in number

Comment: and one more thing when i m passing value from javascript using ajax to its controller(c#) sometimes it works fine but sometime it gives error or 500 which must be because of different datatype. i any one can explain it ??

Comment: 500 is a server error - it would be a 4xx error for a bad request (can't remember off the top of my head)